# Task.Factory.FromAsync equivalent of HttpWebRequest and request stream code

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I have the following extension methods for using asynchronous calls on WebRequest objects.

```
 public static Task<WebResponse> GetReponseAsync(this WebRequest request)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
    }

    public static Task<Stream> GetRequestStreamAsync(this WebRequest request)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null);
    }
```

I would like to convert the following code to an asynchronous equivalent using these extension methods.

```
using (Stream rs = request.GetRequestStream())
{
   var postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData);
   rs.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);

   using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
   {
       str = reader.ReadToEnd();

       rs.Close();
       reader.Close();
       response.Close();
   }
}
```

I did this easily using another piece of code making usage of WebRequest, however that did not require the first call to GetRequestStream().

```
request.GetReponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.Exception == null)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(t.Result.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
});
```

How do I convert the first code block to use my extension methods and be equivalent?

**EDIT** I am using .NET 4.0, so async/await is not currently an option.

Comment: Can you use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`?

Comment: Im not sure, I have never used that before. I would prefer to stay consistent with the second example above if possible.

Comment: In the future, I will be moving towards async/await with 4.5, but one step at a time.

Comment: Since there is no such thing as `StreamReader.BeginReadToEnd`, your continuation will have to handle loops. That's where things start to get *really* complicated and `async` *really* simplifies things. Using `ContinueWith` instead of `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is like forcing yourself to learn (and develop a full solution in) C before you move to C#. In other words, `ContinueWith` is *not* a "step" towards `async`.

Comment: Try `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. It makes this scenarion in .NET 4.0 far easier. You will be moving to 4.5 anyway, so why fix a problem that is already solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to chain the `ContinueWith` calls.  As a rule of thumb, you will have one ContinueWith per async operation in the sequence.  Each ContinueWith will generally end with `return <some async call>` and the next will start process its result.

```
request.GetRequestStreamAsync()
       .ContinueWith((trs) =>
           {
               var postData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("dummy");
               trs.Result.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
               return request.GetResponseAsync();
           }).Unwrap()
       .ContinueWith((resp) =>
           {
               using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.Result.GetResponseStream()))
               {
                   var str = sr.ReadToEnd();
               }
           });
```

Note that in my code (and your asynchronous version), not all of the objects are getting disposed as they were in the original.

At each step, you probably want to either check the Status or IsFaulted/IsCanceled properties or use the overload of ContinueWith that takes a TaskContinuationOptions parameter.  For the latter option, beware that the previous task not completing in a way that matches the options results in a cancelled task.  If you need to pass the errors through, that approach will not.  Personally, I wrap all the checking into a method that either passes through errors and cancellation or runs a delegate on successful completion.  Otherwise, you get a lot of boilerplate checking code very quickly.